# NSNull isEqualToString Issue With JSON Response

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am getting the following error

```
-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3c168090
```

on this line of code

```
cell.offerTitle.text = [voucherData objectForKey:@"offer_title"];
```

Could someone help me correct the problem please?

Thanks
Oliver

Comment: From the looks of it, I suspect that some key in your dictionary is an `NSNull` object for some reason, check all of the keys in your dictionary before attempting to retrieve this object

Comment: Hi,how do I go about checking the above key first is it a case of doing != nil?

Comment: First off, do an NSLog of voucherData, to see what you have.  Also dump your incoming JSON.  NULL is not a legal key value in a JSON "object", but the "far side" could be sending such and the JSON parser just might parse it without complaining (in which case you'd get this symptom).

Comment: Just done that I am getting the following see above update.

Comment: [voucherData objectForKey:@"offer_title"] == NULL should be [voucherData objectForKey:@"offer_title"] == [NSNull null]

Comment: You shouldn't add the answer of your own question inside the question text. This it impossible to mark the question as solved. Instead of updating the question better answer your own question. Do not think of stackoverflow.com as an forum, it is an Q&A platform.

Comment: Thanks, just edited it and placed it in an accepted answer.

Comment: Your answer is the same as what I'd already posted – would you remove your answer and just accept mine instead?

Comment: No Problem, you answered first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is `voucherData` an NSDictionary?

It's possible there's an `NSNull` in your dictionary, and when the dictionary is trying to find the object for `offer_title`, it's running into trouble.

Another possibility is that `[voucherData objectForKey:@"offer_title"]` is returning `[NSNull null]`, and the label is barfing when you try to pass that instead of a string.

Try setting a breakpoint in `objc_exception_throw` and read the stack trace – that will give you a much better idea of what's going on.

**Added:**

```
id value = [voucherData objectForKey:@"offer_title"];
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    cell.offerTitle.text = @"";
else
    call.offerTitle.text = value;
```

or

```
id value = [voucherData objectForKey:@"offer_title"];
cell.offerTitle.text = [value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? @"" : value;
```

Comment: Hi, the voucherData is an NSDictionary, it is a JSON response from the net.

Comment: How would I go about checking for an NSULL as you mentioned before running the next part of the code.

Comment: Added code. But really, to solve problems like this, you should set breakpoints and read stack traces to try to diagnose or solve the problem yourself before posting here. Anything more complex than this would be difficult to debug using intuition alone.

Answer (score 0):

One candidate for best practice here is to use `isEqual:`, not `isEqualToString:`. That way, if what you get is not a string, you won't get an error and the equality test will be failed in good order.

On the other hand you could argue that `isEqualToString:` was a good choice, because when what you got was not a string, you got an error that alerted you to the issue!

EDIT: But that's wrong; see the comments below. The `isEqualToString:` message is coming from UIKit, not from the OP's own code.

Comment: That's not possible here, because the call is in UIKit, not OP's code.

Comment: Very good point. In fact I've had something quite similar happen to me, and it too was in UIKit, not my code. So my answer is wrong; I'll leave it here (edited) in case my mistake can be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

i make some changing for noa's answer

```
-(NSDictionary*)safeData:(NSDictionary*)dict{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
    NSArray *keys = dictionary.allKeys;
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.count; i++){
        id value = [dictionary objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];
        // you can add recursive here
        value = [value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? @"" : value;
        [dictionary setObject:value forKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];
}
    return dictionary; }
```

and use

```
dictionary = [self safeData:dictionary];
```

Answer (score -1):

What that line from the console is likely telling you is that "`voucherData`" is not the "`NSDictionary`" object that you assume that it is.

Also make sure that "`offerTitle`" in your cell is a valid `UITextField` as well.

Comment: If voucherData was null, a silent `nil` would be returned. This is not Java.

Comment: The error is about `-isEqualToString:`, not `-objectForKey:`.